# Node JS - GET request throwing error for a 'where' clause query

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to make a GET request for a single employee row. But code giving reference error xxx not defines

```
app.get('/employee/:sno',function (req,res) {
    mssqlConnection.query('select * from user_login where sno=?',[req.query.sno] ,(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(rows)
        }
        else{
            console.log(err)
        }
    })

})

ReferenceError: sno is not defined
    at C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\index.js:40:67
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\Users\harsh\WebstormProjects\untitled3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Whats your complete request?

Comment: You've setup `sno` as a path parameter, but you're referencing it as a query parameter.

Comment: jake  can you please try to elaborate it please..

Comment: See the answer by @Wyck

Comment: I think there are two distinct problems here.  1)  `req.params` vs `req.query` and 2) Your non-parameterized _question mark syntax_ in the SQL query.  I believe [I answered part 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067869/1563833).

Comment: Consider constructing a parameterized query using [`input` parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value)

Answer (score 1):

With express routing, you access the `:sno` part of `/employee/:sno` with `req.params.sno`

(Not `req.query.sno` as you have done in your question.)

See [Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for reference.

Comment: It is giving this kind of error:   (node:20128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.

Comment: I'm not much of a SQL expert, but it appears that it is complaining about your query:  `select * from user_login where sno=?` ... specifically the `sno=?` part.  Is that legal syntax?  I don't think so.  What are you intending?

Comment: I don't know much SQL, but I was expecting you to construct a parameterized query something like `mssqlConnection.input('sno', sql.VarChar, req.params.sno).query('select * from user_login where sno=@sno')`  I have no idea if this is the exact right syntax.

Comment: @Beginner update your question to include details about the library you are using to perform the database queries. You should also include an example of how the request is being made as it is not clear if you intended to use a path parameter or a query parameter. There isn't enough detail for others to provide a succinct answer.